# Angular Js How to filter records by date?

Tags: angularjs

I am working in angular js and my data is coming from api in json array.I need to add filter according to selected date range from calendar. My dates are coming in two fields "from" and "to" or it can be a single date  and i need to show records according to expiry date in json.

if user select the date range and click on search then i need to get selected records .This is my js in controller file.

```
localStorageService.set('usersOpen', users.openUsers);
localStorageService.bind($scope, 'usersOpen');

users.myUsers = myUsers;
        function myUsers(start_date,end_date){
            DataService.myOpenUsers()
                .then(function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.usersOpen.length = 0;
                $scope.usersOpen.push({'data': response.data.results});
            }, function errorCallback(response) {

            });
```

This is json format that i need to filter.

```
{
  "results": [{
    "id": "999896",
    "description": "Description Testingggg",
    "picturesUrl": [],
    "assigID": [{
      "userId": "67767776",
      "email": "test@gmail.com",
      "firstName": "test",
      "lastName": "User",
      "pictureUrl": "",
      "notifyStatus": "None",

    }],
    "expiryDate": "2016-10-14T17:48:50.100Z",
    "createdUserId": "8887900",
    "status": "Open",
    "dtModified": "2016-10-14T12:21:27.431Z"
  },{
    "id": "999897",
    "description": "New Tested Description",
    "picturesUrl": [],
    "assignedTo": [{
      "userId": "887997",
      "email": null,
      "firstName": "testing",
      "lastName": "users2",
      "pictureUrl": null,
      "notifyStatus": "None",
      "devices": []
    }, {
      "userId": "887997",
      "email": "testing@hotmail.com",
      "firstName": "Testing",
      "lastName": "User2",
      "pictureUrl": "",
      "notifyStatus": "None",

    }],
    "expiryDate": "2016-10-11T09:46:09.100Z",
    "createdUserId": "887997",
    "status": "Open",
    "location": {
      "lat": 12.1,
      "lon": -3.1
    },
    "dtModified": "2016-10-11T09:36:30.217Z"
  }]
}
```

This is html where i am getting records.

```
<ul>                        
<li ng-repeat="users in usersOpen[0].data track by $index" class="{{users.status}} {{yit.id}}">                         
<div class="content-box">
<div class="text-box">  
{{users.description}}   
</div>
{{users.expiryDate}}    
</div>
{{users.firstName}} 
 </li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom filter for filtering date range like this,

**Filter**

```
 app.filter('dateFilter', function() {
      return function(input, start, end) {
        var inputDate = new Date(input),
          startDate = new Date(start),
          endDate = new Date(end),
          result = [];

        for (var i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i++) {
          inputDate = new Date(input[i].DepartureDateTime);
          if (startDate < inputDate && inputDate < endDate) {
            result.push(input[i]);
          }
        }
        return result;
      };
    });
```

and apply in HTML

```
  <div ng-controller="MyController"> 
        <div ng-repeat="data in Combination | dateFilter:startDate:endDate ">
            <div >{{data.DepartureDateTime}}</div> 
        </div>
 </div>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/D7FZ9kX4LEWGmYUXnJ7B?p=preview)**

Comment: Suggest using moment for the date parsing since it's more consistent across browsers.  Also isn't input the array? why is it being converted into a Date? aside from that matches what I had written as an answer.

Comment: from where combination variable is coming..It's not in filter.

Comment: can you please tell me where i can add this in my code?

Comment: @php_dev there is a demo attached

Answer (score 0):

You can use angularjs $filter, you need to inject $filter in the controller and filter in whatever format you wanted.

```
$filter('date')(new Date(expiryDate), "M/d/yyyy");
```

for getting user data within a 2 date range , use this code

```
var fromTime = new Date("2015-04-23").getTime();
var toTime = new Date("2015-04-28").getTime();

var filteredDataByDates = [];
var row, date;

for (i in data) {

  row = data[i];
  date = new Date(row[4]);

  if (date.getTime() >= fromTime && date.getTime() <= toTime) {
    filteredDataByDates.push(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: this filter will only change the format of date.How i can get the records between the selected date range of user?

Comment: Di i need to push all rows one by one in "filteredDataByDates" array or it will filter the complete array.

Comment: no, after the executing the code , you will get data between 2 given dates in the filteredDataByDates array,  so you can bind it to UI, you need to  save  the copy of original data which came from service.

Answer (score -2):

for your problem you can use native Javascript filter :

```
response.data.results.filter(function(user){
    return //add your date test here on user.expiryDate 
}
```